# A question about "as if"

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I wonder whether the following sentence uses "as if" correctly.

> David makes a desk as if it were made by John.

Does this sentence mean "David makes a desk which looks like one made by John"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's confusing to me as a US-English native speaker. Also "makes a desk" is unclear. Like, is he a carpenter building desks? I'd expect to see something more like:

- David makes desks just like John does.
- David makes desks just like John's.

or...

- David makes desks as if the whole world depended on it.
- David makes desks as if he didn't give a damn.
- David is making desks as if he didn't have plans in an hour.

I hope that helps with the kind of tone that **as if** gives. There's a kind of unreal quality to it.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. But in Britain 'as if' is, I believe, used more widely, and 'like' in this sense, less often. For example I might say 'David produces desks to look as if they were John's'. An American (and some in Britain) would probably use 'like' rather than 'as if' here. But I am conditioned by a traditional education to regard 'like' as incorrect here.

Comment: @WS2 So I can say "David produces a desk to look as if it is produced by John"?

Comment: @MatteoGarcía That's exactly how I would say it.